# Table View header hiding like search bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview, uikit

How would I go about letting a table view's header view scroll in and out of bounds even when the table's overall content size is not larger than the bounds. As an example in the Mail.app even in views with no messages you can still scroll the search bar in and out of view (with no scroll bar I should add). How can I get this functionality without using a search display controller/search bar.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting `UIScrollView`'s properties:

```
@property(nonatomic) CGPoint contentOffset
@property(nonatomic) BOOL alwaysBounceVertical
```

Set `contentOffset` to the `height` of the `searchBar` and `alwaysBounceVertical` to `YES`.

That should do the trick!

Comment: That didn't work because offset will only allow you to scroll the view up if the contentSize is bigger than the bounds. So in an empty table view you couldn't scroll it up anymore. Somehow adding a searchbar in IB overrides this, as can be seen in any empty mailbox in mail.app.

Comment: I have edited the answer to include alwaysBounceVertical. Using those two properties makes it work as you describe in the project I'm currently working on. Let me know!

Answer (score 0):

What you see is a special behavior of `UITableView` when its `tableHeaderView` is set to an instance of `UISearchBar`. I believe this behavior is hard-coded. So to get it for your own view you need to extend `UISearchBar`. Or even better, create such a hiding header once and wrap your headers in it when you need the hiding behavior:

```
@interface HidingTableViewHeader : UISearchBar

- (id)initWithHeader:(UIView *)header;

@end

@implementation HidingTableViewHeader

- (id)initWithHeader:(UIView *)header
{
    // We don't really care about the search bar initialization
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // Remove all the sub-views that make up the search bar UI
        [self.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
        // Override UISearchBar's fixed size
        self.size = header.size;
        // Match the tableHeaderView behavior: auto-resize horizontally
        header.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
        // Make the header the only sub-view
        [self addSubview:header];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Use it like this:

```
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = [[HidingTableViewHeader alloc] initWithHeader:someRegularView];
```